# How to suppress static methods on class instance on Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

For example, IntelliJ doesn't show the static sleep method on an instance variable

```
Thread z = new Thread();
z.sleep(1000); // Eclipse shows sleep as part of z, while IntelliJ do not
```

It would appear that sleep is part of z variable

How to prevent Eclipse from showing static methods on instance variable? And how to make that a compilation error if at all possible, Eclipse-wise and in command-line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure you can remove it from options, but you can make Eclipse yield error for that:

Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/warnings -> Non-static access to static member -> set as Error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe more of a workaround but in the *Save Actions* (*Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions*) you can ask to “*Change non static accesses to static members using declaring type*” which will automatically remove such usage.

Also, Eclipse does not normally suggest static proposals first. If it is the case, you should check your *Content Assist* settings (*Preferences->Java->Editor->Content Assist*). Especially, ensure that *Sort proposals* is set to “*by relevance*”.

Comment: +1 if I could find that option in Eclipse. Using Eclipse Indigo if that matter

Comment: As I said it seems that when you ask it to sort completion proposals by relevance, it moves the static methods/fields to the end of the list. I don't think it is possible to completely hide them, but you might want to request it in [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it a compilation error from command line, because object has its class, and on this object you CAN invoke static method, which would affect not only this object. Because of this globally influence it's just a better design to invoke static method from class then from object, that's why IntelliJ prevents you from this.